# Kill ghost on connect to freenode in xchat?

Tags: irc, xchat

how do I automatically kill a ghost nick (e.g. i got disconnected then reconnected) on connect with using xchat? I'm on freenode.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming all versions work the same, you can put /msg nickserv ghost name password as a connect command under server settings for freenode.

[image]

To change your nick as well is a little tricky - type in

> /msg nickserv ghost username password

Then [CTRL SHIFT u a](http://xchat.org/faq/#q214)

> /nick username

As one line. This should do both commands one after another

Answer (score 4):

Try "/msg nickserv ghost  ", without the quotes.

Comment: or rather, `/msg nickserv ghost [username] [password]`. This could be followed up by a `/nick [username]` so you don't end up with the wrong name anyway.

Comment: This is the standard way, not an automatic way as requested.