# Automatically reclaim my IRC nickname (without underscores) globally?

Tags: irc, xchat

I use XChat (2.8.6). It runs 24/7. I think whenever my internet connection is reset (at least every 24 hours), my nickname gets an underscore (`_`) appended:

My nick `john` becomes `john_`, then it becomes `john__`, then `john___` … and so on.

When I click left to the chat text field on my nickname, I can enter a new name. At the moment, I re-enter "john" there everytime and for each server. Which is annoying. **Is there a way to change my nickname globally (= for all servers) back to the registered "normal" form (without underscores) automatically?**

Comment: Asked on Meta why it was closed without any comments: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5681/why-is-my-question-considered-to-be-off-topic

Comment: Just to note, Its an entirely valid question - and different enough from http://superuser.com/questions/90626/kill-ghost-on-connect-to-freenode-in-xchat -> he wants it global

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it happens because the IRC server still thinks for a while that you are online when your internet connection is reset and won't allow you to log in with the same nick. You can explicitly reclaim your stale nick by using the `nickserv ghost` command - manually or by running a script in your IRC client.

Also, you can try using an [IRC bouncer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_%28software%29) - run it on a remote host that's always online.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate how to use this command? I added `nickserv ghost NICKNAME` followed by `nick NICKNAME` to the connection command. This seems to work in some cases … some days my nick is the real one, but some days one `_` is appended (however, thanks to these commands I'd never seen more than one underscore).

Comment: You use it like `/nickserv GHOST NICKNAME PASSWORD` or `/quote nickserv ...` in some irc clients, notably irssi. Providing the password of your registered irc account is essential, otherwise anyone would be able to GHOST you and boot you out.